# Phonegap: get location tag from image in library/album

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, location, exif

`navigator.camera.getPicture` is working reasonably well for me as is `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

If my picture source type is in 0,2 though:

```
Camera.PictureSourceType = {
    PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
    CAMERA : 1,
    SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};
```

is there a ready way to retrieve the location data from these already saved images in phonegap?

I'm calling like:

```
    params = {
        quality: 10
        sourceType: 0
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture @onPhotoDataSuccess, @onFail, params
```

`onPhotoDataSuccess` is then a function of `imageData` which takes a `FILE_URI`.  Can I get the location tag from this, longitude and latitude?

Comment: so far, I still can't get this to work in javascript, jquery.exif.js didn't work.  I would still like a way to do this in javascript.

Otherwise, what is written here works great: https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/geotagsimple

Comment: See similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675322/is-it-possible-to-retrive-an-existing-iphone-images-metadata-specifically-geol