# Is it possible to retrive an existing iPhone image's metadata (specifically geolocation data) using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova, geolocation, exif, photos

I'm using PhoneGap 1.4.1 to create an iPhone application.  I can successfully perform the following tasks:

- retrieve an image from a photo album or the camera roll
- take a new image with the camera
- retrieve the current geolocation of the device

It is my understanding that images taken on the iPhone contain metadata.  I believe the metadata contains the geolocation of where the picture was taken.

I can't seem to find anything in the PhoneGap API about image metadata.
I can already retrieve the device's current location, but I need to access the coordinates of where a picture was taken.

**Is it possible to access the stored geolocation of an iPhone photo using PhoneGap?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a PhoneGap features at the moment but you can still do it in Objective-C.

Here are some link to help you do it

[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos)

[Adding metadata to iOS images](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/)

[Google code : iPhone EXIF](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/)

Then if you can't to use it with PhoneGap, you'll probably have [to create a PhoneGap Plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS)

Comment: Thank you TDeBailleul.  Do you know of any existing PhoneGap Plugins to perform such a task, or will I need to create something from scratch?

Comment: I've never heard of a plugin doing such a thing and I couldn't find anything after doing some research so I think you're gonna have to do  ti.